# Special char added to css (â€‹) where did this come from?

Tags: css, utf-8, character-encoding, notepad++, replace

I was doing a bunch of search-replace operations in notepad++ to effectively minify my css - mostly removing whitespace/tabs etc...)  This ended up breaking much of my css.

Apparently a strange character (â€‹) was inserted all over the place)  Using notepad++ in UTF-8 without BOM, I cannot see these, but they appeared in a view-source.

I was able to remove these by doing a search replace in ANSI encoding, but my question is, what is this character, and why might it have appeared?

Comment: Do you know if any of your code pasted in from an application like MS Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string “â€‹” is the UTF-8 encoded form of ZWSP when misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded data. (Checked this using a nice [UTF-8 decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder).) This explains why you don’t see it in Notepad++ in UTF-8 mode; ZWSP (zero-width space) is an invisible character with no width.

Apparently browsers are interpreting the style sheet as windows-1252 encoded. Saving the file *with* BOM might help, since then browsers would probably guess the encoding better. The real fix is to make sure (in a server-dependent manner) that the server sends appropriate Content-Type header for the CSS file.

But if this is the only non-Ascii character in your CSS file, it does not matter in practice, after you have removed the offending data.

I don’t know of any simple way to make Notepad++ insert ZWSP (you could of course use general character insertion utilities in the system), so it’s a bit of mystery where it came from. Perhaps via copy and paste from somewhere.

Comment: Just an FYI for the reader:  Years ago, I saw this start popping up in my external JS files and IE refused to run my JS.  I discovered that it was an encoding issue caused by improper settings in Adobe GoLive.  If I remember correctly, the character was inserted by GoLive upon FTP upload to the server.  Now I no longer use WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!.  Bonus points if you have a `.htaccess` snippet to ensure proper content-type for my css ;-)

Comment: Zach L, if your .css files are UTF-8 encoded (and any pure-ASCII file trivially is), you can use the following in `.htaccess`:
`AddType text/css;charset=utf-8 css`

Answer (score 1):

Using the web developer plug in or ext in Firefox you can see the problem character in the css document.

In Visual Studio all I could see was:

```
}
.t
```

Web developer showed an unwanted hidden character,  an "a" with a caret on top:

```
}
â.t
```

The utf encoder link above revealed this

```
} (the encoded character for ampersand)
.t
```

and this

but simply fix the problem by deleting and retyping.